# How to make printf run only once in loop

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

How to let printf run only once in loop, the P is argv so it will print Guess 4 times if the value of P is 4

```
while (h!=P) {
 for (int i=0;i<P;i++)
     { 
     n[i]=1,j[i]=1;
     printf("\nGuess:");
     scanf("%d",&guess[i]);
     }
```

Output example

```
1 3 4 1
Guess:1 3 4 1

Guess:
Guess:
Guess:
4H0X
correct

1 4 1 2
Guess:4 1 2 1

Guess:
Guess:
Guess:
0H4X
Guess:
```

Comment: There's really no nice and simple way to detect if the user write multiple values on one line, or one value per line (in which case your current code would work fine). You could [read the whole line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and then manually parse it to extract the values, but it will become messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while (h!=P) {
 printf("\nGuess:");
 for (int i=0;i<P;i++)
 { 
 n[i]=1,j[i]=1;

 scanf("%d",&guess[i]);
 }
```

I think just by putting that printf out from the FOR you can make it

Answer (score 1):

If you wnat only one "Guess" per for loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<P;i++) {
    ...
    if (i == 0)
        printf("\nGuess:");
    ...
    }
```

Comment: And what happens when the user of the program just enters a single value?